# unable to download video created using moviepy in django

Tags: python, django, moviepy

I am trying to import a video, add a watermark and then download the processed video in django using moviepy.
The problem is that I am able to save the processed video to my computer by specifying an absolute path to the computer drive. However, I have not been able to download this processed video. I have tried researching on the internet. However, no luck till now. 
 below is my code:

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import numpy as np
from .forms import UploadFileForm
import tempfile
import os
from django.core.files.storage import default_storage
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage
import sys
import moviepy.editor as mp


from .utils import CFEVideoConf, image_resize

# Create your views here.
def watermark(request):
    if request.method=="GET":
        form = UploadFileForm()
        return render(request, 'video_et.html', {'form':form})
    else:
        if request.method=="POST":
            form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
            if form.is_valid():
                fs = FileSystemStorage(location='/media')
                x = bytes()
                #arr=cv2.VideoWriter()
                image = request.FILES['Watermark_Image']
                video = request.FILES['Video_File']
                print("Name of the Watermark Image: ", image.temporary_file_path())
                print("Name of the Video: ", video.name)

                file_name1 = default_storage.save(video.name, video)
                file1 = default_storage.open(file_name1)
                file_url1 = default_storage.url(file_name1)
                print("file url= ",file_url1)
                url_now1 = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/"+file_url1

                #image = request.FILES['Watermark_Image'].read()

                file_name2 = default_storage.save(image.name, image)
                file2 = default_storage.open(file_name2)
                file_url2 = default_storage.url(file_name2)
                print("file url= ",file_url2)
                url_now2 = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/"+file_url2


                video = mp.VideoFileClip(url_now1)

                logo = (mp.ImageClip(url_now2)
                          .set_duration(video.duration)
                          .resize(height=50) # if you need to resize...
                          .margin(right=8, top=8, opacity=0) # (optional) logo-border padding
                          .set_pos(("right","top")))

                final = mp.CompositeVideoClip([video, logo])
                final.write_videofile("C:\\Users\\win10\\Desktop\\experiment\\django-poc\\media\\test.mp4")
                response = HttpResponse(video, content_type="video/mp4")
                response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=test.mp4'
                return response
```

As shown, the video gets saved in the path "C:\Users\win10\Desktop\experiment\django-poc\media\test.mp4". - this I can play.

the server also produces a test.mp4 as a downloaded file. which cannot be played.

Please help in downloading the processed videofile as an attachment. Any help on this is deeply appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Return a  [`FileResponse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#fileresponse-objects)

Comment: @RossRogers, Thank you for your response. This helped.
return FileResponse(open('test.mp4', 'rb'), as_attachment=True, filename='test.mp4') works. Thank you so much!